# Static member in header-only library

Tags: c++

I'm creating header-only library and I have to use static member.
Is it possible to define it in the header file without redefinition warning?

Comment: Explicit `inline` might help for definition.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to have static data members in a header-only library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709859/how-to-have-static-data-members-in-a-header-only-library)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about a static *data* member, since a static function member is no problem, there are various techniques for different cases:

- Simple integral type, `const`, address not taken:
  Give it a value in the declaration in the class definition. Or you might use an `enum` type.
- Other type, logically constant:
  Use a C++11 `constexpr`.
- Not necessarily constant, or you can't use `constexpr`:
  Use the templated static trick, or a Meyers' singleton.

Example of Meyers' singleton:

```
class Foo
{
private:
    static
    auto n_instances()
        -> int&
    {
         static int the_value;
         return the_value;
    }
public:
    ~Foo() { --n_instances(); }
    Foo() { ++n_instances(); }
    Foo( Foo const& ) { ++n_instances(); }
};
```

Example of the templated statics trick:

```
template< class Dummy >
struct Foo_statics
{
    static int n_instances;
};

template< class Dummy >
int Foo_statics<Dummy>::n_instances;

class Foo
    : private Foo_statics<void>
{
public:
    ~Foo() { --n_instances; }
    Foo() { ++n_instances; }
    Foo( Foo const& ) { ++n_instances; }
};
```

Disclaimer: no code touched by a compiler.