# Define a static variable in header only using macro

Tags: c++, c++11, static, macros

My goal is to be able to create a static variables solely in header with a macro that would take care of initializing it in a `.cpp` file for me with value I've provided. It should look something like this:

```
struct UserDefaults {
    STATIC(bool, isFullscreen, true)
    STATIC(bool, isBorderless, false)
    STATIC(std::string, profileName, "") 
}
```

Which would be equal to:

```
// .hpp file
struct UserDefaults {
    static bool isFullscreen;
    static bool isBorderless;
    static std::string profileName;
}

// .cpp file
bool UserDefaults::isFullscreen = true;
bool UserDefaults::isBorderless= false;
std::string UserDefaults::profileName = "";
```

I've looked at [How to have static data members in a header-only library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709859), but I wasn't able to apply Pesche's solution for my case.

Comment: There is no way a single macro can do that kind of separation.  You would need to use a pre-processing script that is run prior to compiling to analyze the source and generate such code.

Comment: It seems like I heard a discussion about a topic similar to this years ago and the end result was the decision to use static member functions...the function has a single member variable that returns a reference...templates may also be a way to do it...

Comment: @RemyLebeau I know there isn't a single macro solution. I tried to somehow use the solution using templates from the question I posted with creating macros for initializing, reading and writing.

Comment: macros just make obfuscated code that's un-debuggable and unreadable. Can't you just tap the keyboard 20 more times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

#define STATIC(type, name, value) \
    static type& name() { static type ret = value; return ret; }

struct UserDefaults
{
     STATIC(bool, isFullscreen, true)
     STATIC(bool, isBorderless, false)
     STATIC(std::string, profileName, "")
};

int main()
{
    UserDefaults ud;

    std::cout << ud.isFullscreen() << " " << ud.isBorderless() << " " << ud.profileName() << std::endl;
}
```

Output

```
1 0
```

Comment: why is `isFullscreen` `int` not `bool` ?

Comment: I was using exactly what you proposed, but the problem is that you can't write to that value only read from it. I need it to be a static variable.

Comment: @Maroš Beťko: look at it carefully !  those static functions return a reference to a static variable inside of them ,so you CAN assign to them.

Answer (score 0):

Why use macros at all? This is c++.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template<class Type, Type(*init)()>
struct static_thing
{
    using value_type = Type;

    operator value_type&() const {
        return get();
    }

    static value_type& get() {
        static value_type _ { init() };
        return _;
    }

    /*
     * add whatever operations you need
     */

     template<class Source>
     value_type& operator=(Source&& value) {
        get() = std::forward<Source>(value);
     }

     friend auto operator<<(std::ostream& os, static_thing const& st) -> std::ostream&
     {
         return os << st.get();
     }
};

inline bool make_true() { return true; }
inline bool make_false() { return true; }
inline std::string empty_string() { return std::string(); }



struct UserDefaults
{

    static_thing<bool, make_true> isFullscreen;
    static_thing<bool, make_false> isBorderless;
    static_thing<std::string, empty_string> profileName;
};


int main()
{
    auto defs = UserDefaults();

    defs.profileName = "foo";

    std::cout << defs.profileName << " " << defs.isFullscreen << std::endl;

}
```